# python sqlite3 BASE_DIR is not recognized as the name

Tags: python

I use Windows 10 and I just start python
[image: make the default sqlite3]

1. why my root code is just `'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'`,
   When searching, many people come up with  `'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')`, this way. Why am I only different?
2. When I try to check the database, it cannot be checked. However, it is possible to update the database through migration.
   How can I check the make sqlite3 of data?

```
(fcdjango_env) PS C:\python_mvt\fc_community> sqlite3 db.sqlite3

sqlite3: The term 'sqlite3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: 1. `/` is a new python operator related to pathlib https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators

Comment: 2. you need to install sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module for make address for root of your project

```
import os 
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
DB_PATH = os.path.join (BASE_DIR , 'db_test_dir\database.db')
print(DB_PATH)
```

and if you want more complex path for file system you can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You asked two questions:

1. You were seeing *settings.py* file in your project folder.**'NAME':
   BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'** is in DATABASES dictionary which contains
   all databases in your Django project. The first item is **‘default’**
   (the default database). **‘NAME’** means the path to the database file.
   In your project the path is **BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'**. Look at the
   name **BASE_DIR**, it is the naming convention of constants in python
   (and many other languages), words in capital letters separated with
   underscore. At the top of *settings.py* **BASE_DIR** is defined as
   **BASE_DIR = Path(**file**).resolve().parent.parent** So it is a Path
   object. It is instantiated by passing **file** special variable
   (which contains absolute path of current module here *settings.py*) to
   constructor of Path class, then resolving it (i.e. turning any
   symlinks and environment variables to their actual values), and at
   the last get the folder that is two levels up in the filesystem
   hierarchy by using parent twice. The result is a Path object. For
   Path objects there is / operator which can be used to append
   relative path of a folder or a file to the object path. Here
   **BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'** means add filename **db.sqlite3** to **BASE_DIR** path. In simple words **BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'** means **db.sqlite** file which
   located two folders up from current file (*settings.py*). You can
   achieve appending **db.sqlite** to **BASE_DIR** by using **join** module-level
   function of **os.path** module. You are not supposed to use / operators
   of Path objects exclusively. The result is the same.
2. You typed the command of **sqlite3 db.sqlite3** and here you passed
   **db.sqlite3** argument to **sqlite3.exe** which must be either in the current directory of path of it must exists in PATH system environment variable. Hence the error means you either have not installed SQLite v3 on your system or have not added its path to PATH system environment variable. For installing SQLite v3 go to
   https://www.sqlite.org/download.html.